# sort list of objects by arrays dimension wrapped in object

Tags: c#

Sorting a list of array by a particular dimension is easy:

```
var test = new List<float[]>
{
    new[] {0.0f, 0.0f},
    new[] {0.0f, 0.25f}, 
    new[] {0.25f, 0.25f}, 
    new[] {1f, 1f}, 
    new[] {0.25f, 0.75f}, 
    new[] {1f, 1f}, 
    new[] {0.0f, 0.0f},
};

test = test
    .OrderBy(arr => arr[1])
    .ToList();
```

I have the situation where these arrays are wrapped in objects/classes:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public TestClass(float[] array)
    {
        SomeArray = array;
    }
    public float[] SomeArray { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to sort a list of these objects:

```
var X = new List<TestClass>
{
    new TestClass(new[] {0.0f, 0.0f}),
    new TestClass(new[] {0.0f, 0.25f}),
    new TestClass(new[] {0.25f, 0.25f}),
    new TestClass(new[] {1f, 1f}),
    new TestClass(new[] {0.25f, 0.75f}),
    new TestClass(new[] {1f, 1f}),
    new TestClass(new[] {0.0f, 0.0f}),
};
```

by a given dimension (e.g. 0 or 1 in this scenario). Please note that I already implemented CompareTo of TestClass for another purpose. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
X = X
    .OrderBy(i => i.SomeArray[1])
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

The obvious approach is just looking in the objects:

```
var dim = 0;

var sorted = (from x in X
              orderby x.SomeArray[dim]
              select x
             ).ToList();
```

(Using an implementation of one of the various compare/equality interfaces doesn't give the ability to parameterise the sort.)